# python3 regex pattern to separate items on a line

Tags: python, regex

I don't know regex ... I have a file with lines like this:

```
1143 296 'D:\\ssTEST\\TEST_VIDS IMAGES\\2022-11-Tasmania renamed\\01\\2022_11_08_03_49_03_000000_rot_090_1080x1920__20221108_144850.mp4'
1426 320 'D:\\ssTEST\\TEST_VIDS IMAGES\\2022-11-Tasmania renamed\\01\\2022_11_08_03_49_22_000000_rot_090_1080x1920__20221108_144908.mp4'
1733 319 'D:\\ssTEST\\TEST_VIDS IMAGES\\2022-11-Tasmania renamed\\01\\2022_11_08_03_49_45_000000_rot_090_1080x1920__20221108_144932.mp4'
```

What regex string can separate parts of a line into integer_1, integer2, string_without_quotes ?

ChatGPT has had a few goes and can't manage it:

```
#line_parts = re.findall(r"'([^']*)'|\S+", line.strip())
#line_parts = re.findall(r"'([^']*)'|\d+", line.strip())
#line_parts = re.findall(r"'([^']*)'|\b\d+\b", line.strip())
```

Thanks

Comment: Don't use ChatGPT. It's a good text synthesizer, but at a logical reasoning level is comparable to a monkey, if not worse... The text it has generated for you is just cut and glued from sources related to regex, with only some far away semblance of working in the expected way.

Comment: It does try hard and provides reasonable options if you are prepared to work at it.  Sometimes it is plain wrong and you need to fix it bit by bit. And it can and does forget some code it just fixed, in the next answer it gives you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import regex as re    # Use the standard Regular Expressions Library

# Open the input file with a context manager in read only mode
# (This closes the filename automatically when finished)
with open(filename, 'r') as file:
    lines = file. Read()    # read in all the lines in the file
    for line in lines:
        # Step through each line and use re.findall() to return
        # a tuple containing (digits, digits, string) as
        # the regexp groups request
        parts = re.findall(r"^([0-9]+)\s+([0-9]+)\s+'(.*)'$", line.strip())
        print(parts)
```

Output:

```
[('1143', '296', 'D:\\ssTEST\\TEST_VIDS IMAGES\\2022-11-Tasmania renamed\\01\\2022_11_08_03_49_03_000000_rot_090_1080x1920__20221108_144850.mp4')]
[('1426', '320', 'D:\\ssTEST\\TEST_VIDS IMAGES\\2022-11-Tasmania renamed\\01\\2022_11_08_03_49_22_000000_rot_090_1080x1920__20221108_144908.mp4')]
[('1733', '319', 'D:\\ssTEST\\TEST_VIDS IMAGES\\2022-11-Tasmania renamed\\01\\2022_11_08_03_49_45_000000_rot_090_1080x1920__20221108_144932.mp4')]
```

Findall has returned the numbers as strings, but that's easily fixable.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: for windows I had to change .strip() to .rstrip(os.linesep).strip('\r').strip('\n').strip() ... overkill but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

```py
re.findall(r"^(\d+)\s+(\d+)\s+'([^']+)'$", line.strip())
```

Comment: just checking, will that return only 3 items in a tuple in a list of 1 ?